# Calendar/iOS - move event from Google Calendar leaves original

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

Calendar event in Google Calendar.

iOS Calendar.app

If I modify the the calendar, to either iCloud or local calendar, it does not move the calendar, it makes a copy.

The result is: two calendar entries side-by-side.

This has been happening for a while (maybe a year or two).

This doesn't happen when I use Calendar.app to move events *into* Google Calendar.

(NOTE: Google Calendar app in iOS does not let you change the calendar of an existing event).